# How to use fromInteger with no implicit prelude in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, ghc

The following program yields an error in ghci:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}

import Prelude (Integer, Bool)
import qualified Prelude

class Discrete a where
    (==) :: a -> a -> Bool

instance Discrete Integer where
    (==) = (Prelude.==)

class Monoid a where
    one :: a
    (*) :: a -> a -> a

    fromInteger :: Integer -> a
    fromInteger 1 = one
```

Namely:

> fromInteger.hs:17:16:
>      No instance for (Monoid Integer)
>        arising from the literal `1' at fromInteger.hs:17:16
>
>      Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Monoid Integer)
>
>      In the pattern: 1
>
>      In the definition of`fromInteger': fromInteger 1 = one

How can I fix it so that 1 can be converted to the value `one` for Monoids? All other integers may (or should) yield `Prelude.undefined` when being applied to `(Monoid a) => fromInteger`.

Please be aware that I am a the opposite of an expert to Haskell so please forgive me in case the answer is obvious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that (with NoImplitPrelude) you can only use integer literals for types for which there is a `fromInteger` function in scope.

So in your code you can only use integer literals to represent instances of `Monoid` and since in your code, `Integer` is not an instance of `Monoid`, you can not use the literal `1` to represent the Integer 1.

To fix this you could create another module which does import the prelude and define `integerOne :: Integer = 1`.

You could then define your `fromInteger` function as:

```
fromInteger x | x == integerOne = one
```